# Execute row SQL script can't read .sql file. I am getting this error

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

2018/02/01 11:20:00 - Execute row SQL script.0 - We can not find field [C:\Users\abc\Documents\xyz\query\record.sql] in input stream!

My steps involve -

1. get variables - input
2. Execute row SQL script - where I am trying to read my query file
3. text file output

In Execute row SQL script I have given C:\Users\abc\Documents\xyz\query\record.sql  in SQL fieldname.

**EDIT**

Clarifying, I want the job to read query (from files) and give a text output all by itself (run and output the select query result).

Comment: What does your SQL script does? Are you sure it produces an output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm copying/pasting the explanation from the docs of two config options from the **Execute Row SQL Script** step:

> **SQL field name**: The field that either contains the SQL to execute or optionally specifies the path to a file that contains SQL to execute

and

> **Read SQL from file**: If checked, then the SQL field name option specifies a file that contains SQL to execute, otherwise the SQL field name option specifies the actual SQL to execute. (Available since 5.0)

So you can't specify a file path in the *SQL field name* option, but you can specify a field from the stream that contains a file path to the desired sql. Otherwise, you should define in this option a field that contains the sql text.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT 1**

As you need to execute a select query from a file, I would recommend the step `Dynamic SQL row`, just as the following image.

[image: how dynamic sql row works]

I think it will do the job.

**EDIT 2**

The following just do the dynamic sql execution. First, you need to load the sql queries into the stream. After that, a job will be executed for each sql. In this job, a variable containing the sql query is set and a transformation is executed next. This transformation basically is a `Input Table` step that fills dynamically the sql box with the previous set sql variable.

[image: pentaho dynamic sql execution]

Now I think it's what you're looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: I approve with a slight comment. Neither the Get variable, neither the Row-SQL steps will start by themselves. You need to put a `Generate row` with limit 1 before the get variable.

Comment: You're right. In fact, the `Execute Row SQL Script` is not meant to start a stream, but you can start one using other steps, not only `Generate Row`, e.g. the `Data Grid` and/or `Input Table`.

Comment: so now I started the transformation with generate rows with limit 1 and after that I am trying to get the file name with get file name option and then I am passing the filename to Execute row SQL script and then in SQL fieldname I am passing filename. but instead of executing the .sql file its printing the uri of the file.

Comment: @P.C you could try the `Data Grid` step. On the *Meta* tab set a field named *filename* of type *String*. In the *Data* tab set the *filename* column to be the path to the sql file. Link this `Data Grid` to the `Execute Row SQL Script` step. Set there the *connection*, the *sql field name* (must be **filename**) and check the *read sql from file* option. It did the job for me. Remember that this step does not output rows from a select statement. It is meant mostly to do insert/update/delete statements.

Comment: I tried these exactly step by step but in my output file the output is the uri again "filename
C:\Users\abc\Documents\xyz\query\record.sql"

moreover I am trying to execute a select statement , execute row sql script must work , right? if not then can you suggest which option will be good to execute select statement from a file?

Comment: @P.C you can try the `Dynamic SQL row` step. In this case, the *SQL field name* option must contain the sql query. In the *Template SQL* box you must define the layout of the returned data (the types and order of columns). I'll add an example in this answer.

Comment: it doesn't work that way, I want a job which can read query and give a text output all by itself.  defining the layout of the returned data is not an option.

read sql file - execute sql - text output

Comment: @P.C just edited my answer again. I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To read an SQL table use the step `Table input`, and copy paste your query into the big text area.

Note that, unless you have complex join in your query, you rarely have to import sql scripts thanks to a very handy `Get SQL Statement` button.

Start with a select statement without parameters. Once it works, replace the variables with ${variable}, and tick the `Replace variable in script` check box. (Warn there are some restrictions due to java SQL Prepared Statement, for example you may not have a variable in the table name).

If you want to get the script from a file, first read the file with a `Table input` in a column and select this column in the `Insert data from step` of the `Table input`.

If you still have variable parameters either in your file, either in the name of the tables you are selecting from, then use a `Modified Javascript` or a `Regex evaluator`, or any other step to replace the variables with they value, and give the resulting SQL script to the table via the `Insert data from step`.

If you have a bunch of file.sql to read, do not forget to check the `Execute for each row` button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: *"If you want to get the script from a file, first read the file with a `Table input`... "*, how is a `Table input` used to read a file? As far as I know this step only executes sql selects...